# axapta 2009 finish journal

Tags: axapta, x++, journal

i need to insert a finish journal to a workorder by x++.
how to set the dimensions, first of all location correctly?

finish journal and referring line is created, but location isn't set, so booking gives an error:

"Lagerungsdimension 'Lagerort' ist eine primäre Ein-/Ausgabedimension und muss daher festgelegt werden."

should be something like "dimension 'location' is a primary dimension and has to be set" in english.

i tried:

```
prodJournalProd.InventDimId = ProdTable::find( myProdID ).InventDimId;
```

without success.

thanks so much for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error in English: "Stock dimension Warehouse is a primary input/output dimension and must consequently be specified."

I suppose the dimension in question (InventDim.InventLocationId) has been left empty though it must be filled in.